# Java libgdx Shooting bullet at direction with constant speed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to get my bullets to fire towards (input coords) at a constant speed.
So far I was able to get it to shoot at the direction but the farther I click (touch, android game) the faster the bullet goes. I have tried different methods by scaling but failed miserably, I have started coding just a month ago and using this as a project to increase my knowledge of how things work before I work on a full game but having too much trouble with this.

This is what I have been using to get the bullet to move towards the direction I want it to, the codes with // in front were other samples I got while browsing through the internet in hopes of getting what I wanted. I have thought of not using velocity to set the direction, but I have no clue of another method for this.

EDIT: All in short, I cannot get all the bullets to move in the same speed, farther I click, higher velocity bullet has.

Any help guys? Thanks a bunch

Player Class :

```
    public void update(float delta) {
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastShot >= FIRE_RATE) {
            bullets.add(new Bullet(position.x + 6,position.y + 6,4,4,Gdx.input.getX() / 2,Gdx.input.getY() / 2));
            lastShot = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<bullets.size();i++) {
        bullets.get(i).update(delta);
    }
}
```

Bullet Class :

```
    public Bullet(float x, float y, int width, int height, float targetX, float targetY) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    position = new Vector2( x , y );
    velocity = new Vector2( 0 , 0 );
    velocity.set(targetX - position.x,targetY - position.y);
    //velocity.set(targetX - position.x, targetY - position.y).nor().scl(Math.min(position.dst(targetX, targetY), speedMax));
}

public void update(float deltaTime) {
    //position.add(position.x + speedMax * deltaTime * ax,position.y + speedMax * deltaTime * ay);
    position.add(velocity.x * deltaTime, velocity.y * deltaTime);
    //velocity.scl(1 - (0.98f * deltaTime)); 
    // Linear dampening, otherwise the ball will keep going at the original velocity forever
    }
```

Comment: `velocity.set(targetX - position.x,targetY - position.y);` Isn't this why it goes faster the farther you click? Rather: how are you defining your targets?

Comment: @jhobbie Yes, It is why it goes faster, but what I mean is I dont know another method of getting the bullet to move towards the direction of my input (mouse click or touch for phone device).
My targets I define it by using libgdx's Gdx.input.isTouched() then Gdx.input.getX() and Gdx.input.getY()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, normalizing vectors should be rather straightforward. Take your components, square them, and add them together (pythagorean theorem) and then divide each component by this result. I.e. `vX = (targetX - position.x)/Math.sqrt(((targetX - position.x) * (targetX - position.x)) + ((targetY - position.y) *(targetY - position.y )))`

Then you can multiply `vX` by some constant, and do the same for a `vY` and then set your velocity.

Comment: That's pretty much what he already did in the one outcommented line. Just in an object oriented way...

Comment: @jhobbie I have tried adding what you said and It seems the bullets dont move, They are adding to the list and world but do not move at all. I may be implementing this the wrong way, I will experiment more with this formula and see if it works, Ill keep you updated, I have also added the Player Class to my question to see if it helps with more details.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that you were using `setVelocity()` on my `newX` and `newY`, I labeled them rather poorly

Comment: @jhobbie I am using velocity.set(newX*speedMax,newY*speedMax) speedMax being my constant, it seemed making the constant higher made them move a bit faster, but not accurate, the bullets fly all over the place. I think I may be using it wrong still

Comment: I think I normalized incorrectly, give it another go?

Comment: @jhobbie Cheers man! this worked like a charm. It is now fireing at constant speed no matter the distance I click. Thanks a million man.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion along the way, glad I could help.